# Do you know ways for getting partial coincidence joins?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, join, pyspark

I am developing a company-identifier using Spark-SQL and basically what I do is:

### Data sides of the join:

- Let's consider a data frame filled with `company_name_1` that I want to match an `ID_number` (1).
- On the other side I have a **"master"** data base containing thousands of `company_name_2` with an `ID_number` provided (2).
- I want to match `company_name_1` (1) to the `ID_number` (2) based on the similarity between `company_name_1` (1) and `company_name_2` (2).

***Important note***: ***cross-join* is not allowed**, data bases are too large.

[image]

### Matching process - cascade:

1. **Standarization process**: Lower/upper + clear symbols.

***Note**: I don't know what is better for these situations, everything upper or everything lower. In my head it doesn't really matter.*

[image]

2. **First Join - pure inner**: Getting a total coincidence match using a simple inner join using the whole name as key.

[image]

3. **Second Join - partial inner**: For the *no-matches* from the first step, I will extract the strangest word (*1 / Term Frequency of the whole word collection**) of each `company_name_1` and `company_name_2`.

[image]

4. **Validation of the match**: Using string distance/similarity algorithms (i.e. Leveshtein and Jaro Winkler) as udf to develop a confidence score to warranty a correct match.

```py
import textdistance

    def jaro_winkler_udf(s1, s2):
        return textdistance.jaro_winkler(s1, s2)
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf


join_correct = df_1.join(df_2, ['strangest_word'], 'inner')\
            .withColumn("levenshtein_score", sf.levenshtein(sf.col("company_name_1"), sf.col("company_name_2")))\
            .withColumn("jaro_winkler_score", jaro_winkler_udf(sf.col("company_name_1"), sf.col("company_name_2")))\
            .withColumn("label_ok", sf.when((sf.col("levenshtein_score") < 7) | (sf.col("jaro_winkler_score") > 0.7), 1).otherwise(0))\
.where(sf.col("label_acierto")==1)\
```

5. **Unify the matches in one df**:

[image]

#### The question

I would like to generate a new *join-key*, like the strangest word, to join the dataframes.

**Do you know any other *join-key* that might work?**

Keys that I have already tryed:

- **Strangest word**: It works well but it is too wide and the match is sometimes incorrect.
- **2 Strangest words**: It works well too, but after validation, there aren not many matches, however, the match is usually correct. So far the best key I have found.
- **N-grams**: Takes too long to process due to the large size of the data sets.
- **Vectorizing**: Takes too long to process due to the large size of the data sets.
- **Fuzzy-join libraries**: Not installed in productive branch.

Comment: no, sorry to say nothing is clear from the beginning, what is a cleaning process, it woill help to have an actual  database, sql of all steps and wanted result in any sql dialect

Comment: I recovered the post, i took me almost a year to clarify it haha @nbk

Comment: you can look at https://mrpowers.medium.com/fuzzy-matching-in-spark-with-soundex-and-levenshtein-distance-6749f5af8f28  that is on of the better approaches, further you can take a loo  at elastic search, which its suffisticated search options